# if i should import like * as foo-func, it is foo-func is not a function error in jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

i has a problem that use jest & library.

in typescript, it sometimes is required that coding like 'import * as ~' when use external library.

but it is make an error on jest.

use code

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

...
moment(...)
```

error in test code

```
TypeError: moment is not a function
```

is it good solution for resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import * as fooModule from 'foo'
```

would import all named exports from module `foo` and assign them to `fooModule` variable. So to give an example if `foo.js` is defined as the following:

```
export const someVariable = 'someVariable';
export function someFunction(){..}
export default defaultFunctionToExport(){
  console.log('This function can be imported by import default syntax');
}
```

Then `fooModule` imported as following `import * as fooModule from 'foo'` will equal to this object:

```
fooModule = {
  someVariable: 'someVariable', 
  someFunction(){...},
  defaultFunctionToExport(){...}
};
```

Therefore when you import moment as `import * as moment from 'moment'` `moment` variable in your code will be containing all the named exports which is an object not a function. Therefore when you call smtg like `moment()` it would throw an exception. If you just need the moment function you can try importing moment module with `default` import syntax i.e.

```
import moment from 'moment' // this would import the default function exported from moment method

or

import fooFunction from 'foo'// fooFunction will be defaultFunctionToExport which is exported by foo module with default keyword
```

Moment documentation is using the syntax you are using for typescript https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/ but I tried with typescript 3.5 with `moment 2.24` and I can confirm using default import would be the correct way of importing here.